# Measure value of switch and translate to understandable value for programms

Tags: windows, operating-system, hardware

I was searching on the internet on how to translate a current to an understandable value for a pc programme (if it helps, I am looking at DCS world specifically).

I have not found any information on how to do this on the internet.

To further explain what I want to do:
I want to make a panel with multiple types of switches, and I want to convert the value of the switch to a custom value into the pc (kind of like a keyboard gives the value of the letter you press, but I want a completely custom value so it doesn't mess with any other key bindings). Not only will there be on/off type switches, but also rotary switches.

These are the types of switches that I want to use:
https://www.delcity.net/store/Switches/

Greetings, Tom

Comment: Google for 'analog and digital I/O  for Windows'.  There is a LOT of info:)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will definitely look it up!